# Can I transfer programs built with hashDist to other computers without rebuilding?

Tags: linux, portability

I have downloaded and installed a set of programs using hashDist.  As far as I can tell, everything has been installed in a folder .hashdist/.

Is it possible to copy this folder to other computers (which have the same Linux distro)?  I.e. Is the folder entirely self-contained?

I'm not familiar with how hashDist works.

Thanks